# Will a rocket need the same fuel and energy going 1 g upwards on Earth as a rocket 1 g in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, rocket-science

Will the gravity of Earth change the result (making the rocket on earth need more fuel and energy than the one in space)? Or it is the same?

Comment: the 1g you're referring to, is $1*gravitational\ acceleration\ on \ earth $ usually estimated at 9.8 m/s^2, so essentially, you are asking if it would take more energy to attain the same acceleration whether there is gravity or not? and thinking about it intuitively, you can think of gravity as "resistance" and in it's absence, you most certainly will need less energy to get to that acceleration.

Comment: The two cases require the same increase in KE, but differ in terms of GPE.

Comment: A rocket is feeling 1g while sitting on the launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

No. A rocket in space would need less fuel since the gravitational force acting on it is less than on Earth. :)

Comment: Can you show it mathematically?

Comment: just do a thought experiment on it